# Como Convertir un String en nombre de Fragment para abrir una clase?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Hola buenas tardes a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano con esta conversión

Tengo un **Spinner** del que obtengo un nombre/cadena,

```
selecNombre= spinner_listado.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Y con ese nombre obtenido del Spinner intento abrir un **Fragment**

```
cargarFragment(new selecNombre);
 
 
private void cargarFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_activity, R.anim.exit_activity, 0, R.anim.exit_activity);
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_nuevo, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Como puedo convertir esa cadena un en Fragment, para poder abrir el Fragment que se ha seleccionado en ese Spinner ?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado con usar `Class.forName("com.example.loquesea.TUFragmento").newInstance();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El nombre debe ser igual a el de la clase para que accedas a el mediante su "package name", por ejemplo:

```
selecNombre= spinner_listado.getSelectedItem().toString();
String myFragmentName = "com.example.myapp."+selecNombre;
```

Al obtener el "package name" con el nombre de la clase puedes usarlo para cargar el Fragment, podrías llamar el método de esta forma

```
cargarFragment(myFragmentName);
```

Este sería tu método para cargar el Fragment:

```
private void cargarFragment(String myFragmentName) {
    //Obtiene la instancia del Fragment
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment)(Class.forName(myFragmentName).newInstance());
    //Realiza la transacción.
    FragmentTransaction ft =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_activity, R.anim.exit_activity, 0, R.anim.exit_activity);
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_nuevo, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, forName me marca un error "Unhandled exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException", si añado la excepcion throws ClassNotFoundException, me marga error newInstance "Unhandled exceptions: java.lang.IllegalAccessException, java.lang.InstantiationException" y si añado la excepcion "IllegalAccessException, java.lang.InstantiationException" entonces me marca error cargarFragmentLinea(myFragmentName);

Comment: Recuerda que "com.example.myapp." es un ejemplo del package name de la aplicación , debes usar el package name  de tu aplicación

Comment: Si lo tengo puesto, pero sigue dando error forName, para quitarlo tengo que añadir esa excepción, y luego la otra, y con esas excepciones puestas pasa a darme error CargarFragment(myFragmentName) con el mensaje surround with try/catch, aplico esos cambios, y ya no aparecen los errores, pero sigue sin cargar el fragment que selecciono del Spinner